# minimal $U$ where $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R} - U$ is not path connected.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, path-connected

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$. We are looking for a minimal cardinality $U$ where $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R} - U$ is not path connected.

First of all, it is obvious that there will be an injection $U \to \mathbb R^k$ for any $k>0$, since we can always find an imbedding $f : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, take the image of $f$, and "go around" whichever coordinates are missed (Say, a line using dimension $k+1$, where we never move across the $k$ dimensions).

My guess is that $U$ will have to be of equal cardinality to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ - since an infinite sphere with $\mathbb R$ dimensions almost seems necessary to remove from $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ to disconnect $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

My question is:

- Is there a smaller set that disconnects $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$?
- If not, is that canonical sphere the same size as $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: What topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}?$

Comment: The topology that matches in every finitely described projection  -- Essentially I mean "The natural one"

Comment: If $\mathbf{R}^\mathbf{R}$ has the product topology, you might need to disconnect each factor, meaning taking away one point. Will $\{0\}^\mathbf{R}$ do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A^+ = \prod_{t \in ℝ} A^+_t$, where
$$
A^+_t=
\begin{cases} (0,∞), & t=0, \\
ℝ - 0, & t \neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Define $A^-$ analogously with $A^-_0 = (-∞, 0)$.

Sets $A^-$, $A^+$ are non-empty, disjoint, and open in $A^+ \cup A^- = ℝ^ℝ - \{0\}^ℝ$. Thus this space is disconnected. Therefore, the singleton $U = \{\{0\}^ℝ\}$ will suffice to disconnect $ℝ^ℝ$ (as [William M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/396761/william-m) suggested in the comments). Disconnected space cannot be path-connected, so the proof is finished.

---

Alternative answer: Use the contrapositive of [the main theorem of connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems), the fact that any projection $π:ℝ^ℝ−\{0\}^ℝ →ℝ-0$ is continuous in natural topology, and the fact that image of projection, i.e. $ℝ-0$, is not connected.

Comment: What is $A^-_9$ supposed to be? Because if it is $\mathbb R - 0$, then $A^-$ and $A^+$ are not disjoint. But it can't be $\{0\}$ since that wouldn't be open (Or is it?) Can't think of the appropriate analogous definition when $t \neq 0$ for $A^-$, could you help me out?

Comment: Hi, @Snared ! You're right that $A^-_9 = ℝ-0$. To see, that $A^+, A^-$ are disjoint it is helpful to think that elements of $ℝ^ℝ$ are functions $f:ℝ→ℝ$ (intuitively $f$ is a point with "infinite" coordinates $(f(x), f(y), f(z) \dots)$). Now we can interpret $A^+$ as a set of all functions for which $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, and $f(0)> 0$. On the other hand, if function $g$ is also not zero everywhere, but it's negative at $0$, that is $g(0) <0$, then it belongs to $A^-$.  Can you see now why $A^+$ and $A^-$ are disjoint?

Comment: Aha, I see - For $A^-$ and $A^+$ to intersect, that would mean some function in both match everywhere. Yes I see how they are disjoint now :)